# AdonisJS doesn't start after installing another npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

I'm developing an AdonisJS API, everything was going well until I install vimeo npm package, after this I cannot set server up appearing this error:

```
$ adonis serve --dev

 SERVER STARTED 
> Watching files for changes...


Error: Cannot find module '@adonisjs/framework/providers/AppProvider'


1 requireStack
  /mnt/c/Users/felip/Desktop/API/2019-2_DevWeb01/API/node_modules/require-stack/src/index.js:44

2 _.uniq.map
  /mnt/c/Users/felip/Desktop/API/2019-2_DevWeb01/API/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/src/Registrar/index.js:104

3 arrayMap
  /mnt/c/Users/felip/Desktop/API/2019-2_DevWeb01/API/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:639

4 Function.map
  /mnt/c/Users/felip/Desktop/API/2019-2_DevWeb01/API/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9554

5 interceptor
  /mnt/c/Users/felip/Desktop/API/2019-2_DevWeb01/API/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:16997

6 thru
  /mnt/c/Users/felip/Desktop/API/2019-2_DevWeb01/API/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:8795
```

I'm using WSL and node 8.9.3, also tried in node 10.17.0.
Also tried to install manually '@adonisjs/framework' and Reinstall all packages, deleting node_modules, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

can you install adonisjs package globally. 
if not then install using this command.

```
npm i -g @adonisjs/cli
```

if any other query then ask

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project has a .env file
or run `cp .env.example .env`